# Clean/Reset All Auto-Increment Primary Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server (2005+), I have a fully working database integrated with a web application.
The database consists of views, keys, indexes, stored procedures, and etc.

Most if not all my tables have auto increment primary keys. Is there an SQL script to clean (reset) all primary fields so they will look better (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 6,...)? taking in consideration the consistency of any related foreign keys.

There is no real motivation to do that except for organizing the data.

Comment: I would ask why this is increasing "organization"? If the relationships are valid that seems pretty organized to me. Nobody sees Auto number fields except joins

Comment: Because for instance I would like to see an approximately valid count. In my case, FieldID can be 4000 whereas I have only 700 records in the table.

Comment: There is no easy way to do it. You would have to recreate all tables. Process for each table would be to create new table, transfer data, drop old FKs, drop old table, rename new table, create new keys. Whatever the reason you would have (and the one you mentioned is not that good), it's simply not worth it.

Comment: If you need a record count, just `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table`. It's a cheap operation and has none of the obnoxious overhead of periodically renumbering your IDs.

Comment: tried truncating tables ?

Comment: @Dreamer sounds like the OP wants to keep the existing data, just shove all the IDs to the front of the number scale

Comment: No technical benefit to this.  Sounds more like an attempt to satisfy an OCD.  Touch the stapler... renumber the keys... touch the stapler... renumber the keys... touch the stapler...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DO NOT EVEN THINK ABOUT DOING THIS.** (Yes I know I was yelling.) This does not make a database more organized it, makes it much more likely to have data integrity problems and much much more likely to have performance problems and tie up the users while you do a cosmetic change that is good for no one. Databases will have gaps over time and that is a good thing as the gaps are from deleted records and records that were rolled back. It helps enable the database to keep things in synch when multiple users are doing transactions at the same time. It preserves data integrity. Further, you do not appear to have a requirement to do this other than you don't like the way it looks. And if I did get a requirement to do something so massively stupid, I would send it back unless the change was something required by law.

Comment: +1 (more if I could)  I tried this one time and will never do it again.  Not worth the risk of data integrity loss.  Tell whoever is asking you to do this that auto-increment keys are neither guaranteed to start at 1 nor be consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

You could set your FKs to UPDATE CASCADE, calculate how the keys need to change and [reseed your tables](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/15/sql-server-dbcc-reseed-table-identity-value-reset-table-identity/), but as HLGEM points out there's no good reason to and many good reasons not to.  If you're not willing to recreate everything on a separate database and port it all over from scratch, don't bother.  You'd really need some compelling reason to update PKs under any circumstance, particularly identity based ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can reseed the values using the following code:

```
DECLARE @MaxID INT
SELECT @MaxID = MAX(ID)
FROM <TableName>
DBCC CHECKIDENT('<TableName>', RESEED, @MaxID)
```

Comment: This just resets the number of next ID to match Max ID (+1).